# Calendar has no right-click with inspect option

Tags: calendar, inspect

I am using this website here https://uk.investing.com/indices/mining-historical-data to download historical data automatically.

However, the calendar to change dates to 01-01-2010 or 01-01-2015 is not allowing me to 'inspect'.

Therefore, I am not able to `setattribute` effectively.

I've tried setattribute as follows;

```
new_element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@class="DatePickerWrapper_input-text__HAN0Z DatePickerWrapper_center__BYe4Q"]""")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('[]','02/08/2022 - 02/10/2022')", new_element)
```

But this does not affect the prompt/current dates shown in the text boxes.